# Difference between uboot-uart.bin and uboot.bin?

Tags: embedded, arm, u-boot

I am trying to flash the very first u-boot binary file (uboot.bin) into blank NOR flash of a brand new blank board which has marvel 370 soc(ARM) using Teraterm(xmodem/ymodem/zmodem)

When I compile the uboot, I get two binaries like uboot-uart.bin and uboot.bin.

What is the difference between two binaries?

I have been instructed to make some dip switch changes and then load uboot-uart.bin first into the prototype board.

From manual I understand that the dip switch setting is to set "Boot from Uart" to Boot source list.

I am new to embedded and want to learn more about this from u-boot perspective. Where can I learn about this?

Would also like to know what these xmodem,ymodem,zmodem things are?

And would also like to learn how to customize u-boot for a custom board using marvel 370 soc(ARM)?

I would be happy if someone can point to good resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XModem itself is a quite simple protocol which is meant to send files over a serial link it is explained in detail [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMODEM).

Most Marvell ARM-Chips in the last couple of years have the possibility to upload a binary via UART using the XModem protocol. There are two ways to do that.

1. By sending a special sequence to the chip during bootup (which can be done without any changes to the bootstrap options).
2. By setting up the bootstrap options accordingly (via DIP-Switches in your case)

In both cases the chip will then initiate an Xmodem-download. TeraTerm should have an option to upload files via the xmodem protocol. IIRC it is available under File/Transfer/XModem/Send.

If you know just send your "uboot-uart.bin" file to the Armada 370 (which will take some time). The SoC will now boot the file just like if it was loaded from NAND or any other source.

The only difference between your uboot-uart.bin and uboot.bin is most probably the special header which has to be put in front of the actual uboot-binary, it contains the bootdevice type the image was meant for, the address in memory where the image should be loaded to and a lot of board specific settings. The exact structure and content is usually explained in the very excellent datasheets from Marvell.

For customizing uboot I can only suggest to dig into the code provided by Marvell and change it according to your own board. You'll find the board specific files under boards/Marvell.

Comment: Thanks Masta79. Few more queries.
Is the uboot-uart.bin loaded into RAM and executed from there?
If yes, how does it know the RAM's address(the address where uboot-uart.bin is to be loaded)?

Comment: Yes it gets loaded into RAM, the RAM is also setup via the information from the images header and also the address for the images comes from there. I've updated my answer to include this information.

Comment: Thanks Masta. Could you please share how to examine the uboot binary?
I would like to see the headers like its done for elf using readelf and objdump

Comment: I don't know about the exact headers used in the Armada370. As you were talking about "DIP Switch changes on the prototype board". I suspect you're in contact with Marvell or one of their distributors and received one of the official development-kits. You should ask them for access to the datasheets, usually they explain the header quite well.